# React-native error when importing web component

Tags: react-native, styled-components, react-native-web

Here I am specifically telling react-native to only show `GlobalStyle` component (created with [createGlobalStyle](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) from `styled-components`) when I am on the web:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {Platform.OS === 'web' && <GlobalStyle />}
        <Navigation /> {/* other top-level stuff */}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Yet, I still get an error, saying: "createGlobalStyle is not a function". Why is this happening if I never show this component on mobile?

Answer (score -1):

You should use Navigator in `ThemeProvider` like

```
import { createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.whiteColor ? 'white' : 'black')};
    font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontFamily};
  }
`

// later in your app

<ThemeProvider theme={{ fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue' }}>
  <React.Fragment>
    <Navigation /> {/* example of other top-level stuff */}
    <GlobalStyle whiteColor />
  </React.Fragment>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Details here [createglobalstyle](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help. The error is the same

Comment: @PetroIvanenko At least someone tried to help you